# Events being shifted down when more than one on a single day with jquery-week-calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-week-calendar

I'm using [jquery-week-calendar](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar) v2.0-dev and when I show two events on the same day, the second event shows the wrong time. When I grab the bottom of the first event with the mouse and start resizing, the second event suddenly appears. I have checked all my `.js` and `.css` files against the demo in `weekcalendar.html` and everything matches. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks! Chirag

[image: See attachment].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a rule like this to your `.css` stylesheets:

```
.wc-cal-event {
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

If you already have the absolute position, the `!important;` was also necessary